# Rails 4 URLGeneration Error issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building out an app, and I decided to Use Devise and CanCanCan.. I have set the app so that only an admin or superuser can add a new user.

My users are created from a modal located on the application.html.erb page.

I can create a new user no problem, everything works. However now I am trying to set it o that a user can edit their profile, once again, from a modal.. this is where I am " hitting the wall".

[This is the github repo for this project feel free to take a look if you want to.](https://github.com/TaurenMaterialSerivcesLTD/Patrol_Vault_Bootstrap/tree/AddsCarrierWave)

I have gone through the code over and over but to no avail!

> **EDIT # 1 - ScreenShot**
>   [image]
>   This is the error message I am getting.

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admins"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Before you jump all over me for not having the id set properly, I am using vanity url's SecureRandom.hex(6) strings. they seem to be fine everywhere else except here.

heres the rake routes output for the Edit User.

```
       edit_user GET    /admins/:id/edit(.:format)        admins#edit
  push_edit_user PATCH  /admins/:id(.:format)             admins#update
```

here is the custom routes in routes.rb

```
  as :user do
    get "admins/new_user" => "admins#new_user", as: :admins_new_user
    post "admins/create_user" => "admins#create_user", as: :admins_create_user
```

> ```
>     get "admins/:id/edit" => "admins#edit", as: :edit_user
>     patch "admins/:id" => "admins#update", as: :push_user_edit
> ```

```
  end
```

here is my users (admin) controller where I have my create and update actions.

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new_user
    authorize! :manage, User
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create_user
    @user = User.find_by_user_ident(params[:user_id])
    authorize! :manage, User
    @user = User.new(sign_up_params)
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'User has been successfully created.' }
    else

    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find_by_user_ident(params[:user_id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find_by_user_ident(params[:user_id])

    if @user.update(account_update_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Address was successfully updated.' }

    else

    end
  end

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :user_ident, :f_name, :m_name, :l_name, :dob, :role)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :user_ident, :f_name, :m_name, :l_name, :dob, :role)
  end

  # Sets user to be found by User_Ident #
  def set_user
    @user = User.find_by_user_ident(params[:id])
  end

  # Allow Profile Update w/o Current p/w Confirmation
  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_without_password(params)
  end

end
```

and just to be safe, here is the full stack trace of the error.

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admins"} missing required keys: [:id]:
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:50:in `generate'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:629:in `generate'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:660:in `generate'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:707:in `url_for'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:236:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:177:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:295:in `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:168:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1028780063709367977_70323361979180'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:158:in `block in render'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:348:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:156:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:66:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:144:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/developer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:30:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:36:in `default_render'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `block in send_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `tap'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:181:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:31:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
  activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/digestor.rb:12:in `call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
  activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
  web-console (3.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:131:in `call_app'
  web-console (3.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (3.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (3.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
  railties (5.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
  railties (5.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
  railties (5.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
  railties (5.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:569:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:271:in `block in run'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance! Please let me know if you need anything else!

> **EDIT # 2 - Application Controller and Modal**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :set_user

  def set_user
    @user = User.find_by_user_ident(params[:user_id])
    @user = User.new
  end

end

<%= form_for(@user, :url => push_user_edit_path) do |f| %>
  <div class="modal fade" id="userEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create New System User</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :email %><br />
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :password %>
            <% if @minimum_password_length %>
            <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
            <% end %><br />
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :f_name %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :middle_name %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :m_name %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :l_name %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :date_of_birth %><br />
            <%= f.date_field :dob %>
          </div>

          <br />
          <%= f.collection_select(:role, User::ROLES, :to_s, lambda{|i| i.to_s.humanize}) %>
          <br />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <%= f.submit "Create User", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

> **EDIT # 3 - ActionController server output**

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admins"} missing required keys: [:id]:
```

this is all that is output as I cant even get to the edit screen or into the app, this happens as soon as I log in as the form is in a modal in application.html.erb

Comment: Where you call this route?

Comment: no Patch, it dose not give me the option to post

Comment: the only way i can POST in this controller is with create, but i always thought POST was only for create and Patch was edit/update?

Comment: Yeah you are wright can you post the params that are sent to update.. I think you are using `params[:user_id]` in your controller but passing `id` as params..

Comment: Are you referring to the Params in set user Params? I have tried both :Id and user_id in the update method both give the same error.

Comment: add your view(html) file in your question..

Comment: can you update the question with the `ActionController::Parameters` as seen in your logs?

Comment: There is no html file just a modal in the application.html.erb, and I have set the user in application controller I'll add those right away.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is coming from your `form_for`.

It should be:

```
form_for @user, url: push_edit_user_path(@user) do |f|
   ...
end
```

Comment: if your rake routes shows `push_edit_user` then I believe you shouldn't be getting the same error. What specific errors are you getting now

Comment: thats what it shows.. its odd I know.. thats why I came here.. lol.. I have no idea whats going on..

Comment: push_user_edit PATCH  /admins/:id(.:format)             admins#update right from rake routes 2 sec ago..

Comment: how about changing to `push_user_edit_path(@user)`. BTW, do you have this project on Github or something?

Comment: yes it is on GitHub, here is the link https://github.com/TaurenMaterialSerivcesLTD/Patrol_Vault_Bootstrap

Comment: the branch this issue is under is AddsCarrierWave, i just havnt added carrierwave yet.

Comment: Is there any reason you're adding 2 forms to the application.html.erb?

Comment: The main reason is for user create / update functions I want them to be modals. As now only an admin can create a new user, but I want the user to be able to edit their profile. Now I'm also brand new to modals so perhaps there is a more effective way to achieve this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115979/discussion-between-oreoluwa-and-shawn-wilson).

Comment: I am back if you would like to continue.